# what are these two this represented for here?

Tags: javascript

One interviewer asked me to explain what is this represented for in the following codes.
I had no idea about that.
Because I have not seen any codes like that before.
Please tell me is there any difference between these two and in what conditions such codes are useful?

```
function A(){
    this.x=1;//No.1
    function B(){
        this.y=2;//No.2
    }
}
```

I only know that when I use new to create a new object ,it has a property x equals to 1;

Comment: It depends on how `A` and `B` are called. Since the value of `this` is evaluated at run time, seeing the definition does not provide any information. You can find all the relevant information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you call the function. If you call it as a regular function, like this:

```
A();
```

then `this` will be the `window` object of the document.

If you use the function as an object constructor, like this:

```
var a = new A();
```

then `this` will be a reference to the newly created object.

The reference `this` in the `B` function will never be anything, as it's not possible to call the function. It's local inside the `A` function and as there is no code in the `A` function that could be use to call the `B` function, it will never be called.

If we make it possible to call the `B` function, the same thing applies as with the `A` function. What `this` is depends on how you use the function. Even if you call the `B` function from within the `A` function when the `A` function is used as a constructor (and thus `this` is an object reference in `A`), the `B` function doesn't inherit `this` from `A`. It's either a reference to `window` (when `B` is used as a function) or a reference to a newly created object (if `B` is used as a constructor).

Answer (score 2):

If this is used in the normal, `window` context, both `this` refer to the window, even though the naming scope is different.

Here is an adjusted version of the code you posted:

```
function A(){
    this.x=1;//No.1
    function B(){
        this.y=2;//No.2
        console.log(this)      // log `this`
    }
    console.log(this)          // log `this`
    B()                        // Run function B()
}
A()                            // Run function A()
```

This logs each `this` in the console. It returns

```
window
window
```

If you call A() from a different context (eg  assigned as an event handler), `this //No.1` will refer to the relevant object. `this //No. 2` will still be `window`.

Comment: *"If you call A() from a different context (eg an event listener), this //No.1 will refer to the relevant object."*: Only if you assign `A` **as** event handler, not if you call it *from* the event handler.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

This.x and This.y refers to window. But you cannot access function B. It'll show error like B() is undefined. see in firebug console mode